# Save state on component object directly?

Tags: reactjs

The react documentation recommends to store a components state in its "state" property. But it appears that it's also well possible to use the component object itself as the state.

For example, instead of doing:

```js
{
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {firstname: this.props.firstname||"",lastname:this.props.lastname||""}
    },
    render:function(){
        return React.DOM.div({},"Hello, "+this.state.firstname+" "+this.state.lastname);
    }
}
```

I could do something like this:

```js
{
    getInitialState:function(){
        this.constructor(this.props);
        return {};
    },
    constructor:function(props){
        this.firstname = props.firstname||"";
        this.lastname = props.lastname||"";
    },
    render:function(){
        return React.DOM.div({},"Hello, "+this.firstname+" "+this.lastname);
    }
}
```

To me this looks much cleaner. But I'm afraid that this could have any unexpected side effects that I'm unaware of.

Is this a bad idea? Will it have any disadvantages? Why do you think did the React devs even go for a "state" property? I mean, if it worked the way I'd like it worked by default, the state-property-pattern could still be used by everyone that prefers it, but those who don't like it wouldn't need to even have a "getInitialState" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is built on top of the idea that a component always reflects the components 'state'. 
When altering state with setState, React will rerender the parts that have been altered.

Internally, a React component is a javascript object just as everything else. 
So of course you can alter properties directly, but this will not prompt react to rerender the component. Thus, your component will not always reflect the altered properties.

Thus, even if it would work to alter properties directly, it's a bad design-pattern since it's harder to refactor to state if you ever need it. It also breaks the standard design-pattern of React, which will make it harder to read for other developers.

Comment: `When altering state with setState, React will rerender the parts that have been altered.` React does always a full rerender and then diffs the new virtual DOM against the old one and then calculates a patch, as far as i know. So `render` is called after every `setState` anyway. It doesn't matter if use `setState` or change the state manually and the call `forceUpdate` the result should be the same, right? Or are there any downsides of this? (aside from the last thing you correctly mentioned)

Comment: @VanCoding Yes, it's as you say, you could call `forceUpdate`. In this case, it's just a sign of a bad practice. In other places, like when using immutable data structures, using `forceUpdate` would be even _the right solution_.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the component object to store the state, but it is not good idea when the state changes. If the state does not change during the component's life-cycle I see no technical reason why you could not use this style.

When the state in component changes, this object style has no point. The state change causes to re-render if there is no other logic overriding the default `shouldComponentUpdate` method. Also the state changes are applied in batch if possible to increase the performance.

[image: The update life-cycle from]

Great resource for this is the React's document why the state object should be used. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Image from http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-the-react-framework--net-35660

Comment: Yes, the `setState()` function would be totally useless, but wouldn't changing the state manually & then calling `forceUpdate()` be exactly the same? I understood it like this: When I call `setState()` then `forceUpdate()` is called automatically internally. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Seems so according to React code comments https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b2db10f43e9781d9925b01be8bb55de24c5bf1ce/src/isomorphic/modern/class/ReactComponent.js#L92